# Is it safe to store state on a component instance in React?

Tags: reactjs

Before React 16 it was considered dangerous to store state in a component instance (assigning to this.whatever). The React runtime could recreate instances at any time.

This warning has disappeared from the docs. Does this mean it is safe to use `this` to store state that should not trigger a re-render?

Comment: *The React runtime could recreate instances at any time.* - do you have specific source to refer to? Under which circumstances they could be recreated? AFAIK React component mount/unmount lifecycle didn't change in this regard.

Comment: It was an old version of the React docs. When React.createClass was still the way to create a component instance.

Comment: createClass was deprecated in 15. Is it possible that you remember it the wrong way? componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount works similarly with createClass . Otherwise React would be a pain to deal with right from the beginning. Any way, this is not a concern for React 16.